# supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, swift2, appdelegate, uiinterfaceorientation

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue.hashValue | UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown.rawValue.hashValue
}
```

That used to work in Swift 1.2 however the return line is now throwing this error:

> Binary operator '|' cannot be applied to two
>   'UIInterfaceOrientationMask' operands

I am able to get to work with just 1 return value with the new type but I cannot get it to pipe the second orientation I need.

This 'works'

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait 
}
```

But what I 'think' I need is this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown
}
```

And it says the same error as I posted above.

Do you know how to properly set the orientation to 2 or more values in the in the AppDelegate in Swift 2.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try new syntax:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
  return [.Portrait, .PortraitUpsideDown]
}
```

Comment: Curious how you figured this out!