# Unable to force UIViewController orientation

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, screen-rotation

I have a portrait application with one landscape ViewController.

I've been digging a lot on how to force the orientation to landscape when the app is locked to portrait and I tried a lot of solutions presented here and not only but without any luck so far.

So far I managed to autorotate the VC I need in landscape but since the orientation is not locked, all other VCs will also rotate.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight.rawValue
    UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool
{
    return true
}
```

After some more digging I ended up with this after finding a sample project but while it works in that project, it doesn't seem to work for me.

This is in AppDelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    if self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController is ConclusionReferencesVC {

        let conclusionReferencesVC = self.window!.rootViewController!.presentedViewController as! ConclusionReferencesVC

        if conclusionReferencesVC.isPresented
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeRight;
        }
        else
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
    }
}
```

This is in the VC I want to have in landscape:

```
var isPresented = true

@IBAction
func dismiss()
{
    isPresented = false
    self.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
}
```

For some reason, the supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow method does not validate the initial condition.

I also tried these among others but no luck:

[How to lock orientation of one view controller to portrait mode only in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938660/how-to-lock-orientation-of-one-view-controller-to-portrait-mode-only-in-swift)

[supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow in Swift 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634110/supportedinterfaceorientationsforwindow-in-swift-2-0)

Any ideas? It seems I'm missing something but I can't figure it out what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this for force to `LandscapeRight` mode only

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if(self.supportedInterfaceOrientations() == UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeRight && UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation != UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight)
        {
            let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight.rawValue
            UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
        }

    }
```

and then use a category like this

```
    import UIKit

extension UINavigationController{

    override public func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool
    {
    return (self.viewControllers.last?.shouldAutorotate())!
    }

    override public func supportedInterfaceOrientations() ->UIInterfaceOrientationMask
    {
    return (self.viewControllers.last?.supportedInterfaceOrientations())!;
    }

    override public func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation()-> UIInterfaceOrientation
    {
    return (self.viewControllers.last?.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation())!;
    }

}
```

### EDITED

If you are not using navigation controller use this

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if(self.supportedInterfaceOrientations() == UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeRight && UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation != UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight)
        {
            let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight.rawValue
            UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
        }

    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() ->UIInterfaceOrientationMask
    {
        return .LandscapeRight;
    }
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks @ReinierMelian but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @daydr3am3r First of all you are using a navigation controller?

Comment: Nope. And that's why is not working. Sorry. I should have mentioned it before.

Comment: @daydr3am3r I have this implemented in 2 of my apps but having navigation controller on it, so I will check without navigation controller, and I post my results, if I have some ;)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to see if I can also come up with something and post back.

Comment: @daydr3am3r check my answer was edited, for me works perfect with this code

Answer (score 1):

As an update to [Reinier Melian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6190582/reinier-melian)'s post, here is the UINavigationController extension in Swift 3:

```
import UIKit

extension UINavigationController {
    override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return (self.viewControllers.last?.shouldAutorotate)!
    }

    override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return (self.viewControllers.last?.supportedInterfaceOrientations)!
    }

    override open var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
        return (self.viewControllers.last?.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation)!
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this code crashes if you call a UIImagePickerController, as that is contained within a UINavigationController whose last view controller is nil.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

probably I´m crazy ;-), but why don´t u use this?

[image]

Comment: The problem is that @daydr3am3r need landscape on 1 viewController only, your answer make all the app only on landscape

Comment: oh, don´t see that! :-(  Now i understand... Thanks!

Comment: don't worry it happens

Comment: @UlliH - Thanks for the suggestion. However the app was initially designed for Portrait only mode and now I need to insert a landscape screen.

Comment: @daydr3am3r ok, i´m crazy ;-)