# Rotation behaviour iOS8 vs iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uikit

I have a app that is locked to portrait in all views except one that is AllButUpsideDown. The approach i am using is to enable Portrait, Landscape Left and Landscape Right in the targets general settings menu. Then have subclasses of UINavigationController and UITabBarController that override `func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask` and returns `.Portrait`.

Then in my view controller that needs to be able to be rotated I have also overridden `func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask` and returns `.AllButUpsideDown`. This works fine since this view controller is only presented as a modal i.e `aViewController.presentViewController()`.

All of this work as expected on iOS9 on iOS8 however if i close the rotatable view controller while in landscape the UI will be scaled to landscape altho it will be displayed in portrait.

[image: result in iOS8]

Anyone know what to do about this? Am I approaching this rotation thing wrong from the start? Any clean fixes? Workarounds? Hacks?

**UPDATE**

My problem originated from me using a custom transition to present and dismiss the view controller that could rotate. I tried to work around it for some time with bunch of different solutions. The closest I got to a solution was to use a separate UIWindow for my rotatable view controller, that worked except a issue with the carrier bar still being in the wrong orientation, and that was something I did not manage to solve.

The solution(not really a solution) I went with was to only use the custom transition in iOS9+ and on iOS8 use the default present transition.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308919/unable-to-force-uiviewcontroller-orientation/38308987#38308987

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue when navigation back from VC, that supports landscape to the one that is only portrait. I didn't find a clean workaround. These couple of lines are not recommended to use, but if you are desperate you can force your device orientation when you are about to dismiss.

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```