# Crash when locking screen orientation in SwiftUI using UIDevice.current.setValue()

Tags: ios, swiftui, crash, uikit, orientation

My SwiftUI app needs to lock some views into Landscape and others into Portrait, so I was using the popular UIDevice.current.setValue() technique from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66037782/swiftui-how-do-i-lock-a-particular-view-in-portrait-mode-whilst-allowing-others) and others. I was really happy with this solution but now it seems to be crashing our app.

The exception is "doesNotRecognizeSelector." Stack trace below.

So I am locking the orientation inside a SwiftUI View's onAppear method:

```
onAppear {
       setStackScreen() // Function to make sure we are no longer in split screen, if we came in from a split-screen view
       UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait, forKey: "orientation")
       AppDelegate.orientationLock = .portrait
}
```

Any thoughts on what might be going wrong here? Here is the crash message.

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x180c4fd0c __exceptionPreprocess + 216 (NSException.m:200)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x198440ee4 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x180d20750 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 140 (NSObject.m:147)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x180be960c ___forwarding___ + 1472 (NSForwarding.m:3577)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x180be881c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92 (:-1)
5   Foundation                      0x182314740 _NSSetLongLongValueForKeyWithMethod + 76 (NSKeyValueAccessor.m:116)
6   Foundation                      0x1822f8fc8 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 312 (NSKeyValueCoding.m:437)
7   MyApp                           0x10093bc04 closure #2 in closure #1 in MySwiftUIView.body.getter + 480
8   SwiftUI                         0x1882a76bc closure #1 in _AppearanceActionModifier.MergedBox.update() + 92 (AppearanceActionModifier.swift:0)
9   SwiftUI                         0x188326ea0 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 20 (<compiler-generated>:0)
10  SwiftUI                         0x18824cf24 closure #1 in ViewRendererHost.render(interval:updateDisplayList:) + 2336 (<compiler-generated>:0)
```

Comment: That `UIDevice.current.setValue()` solution has never been valid. Your crashing app demonstrates why.

Answer (score 1):

I found out this doesn't work anymore. There is a [better way](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQUI/blob/master/Sources/AQUI/OrientationLock.swift) involving subclassing UIHostingController and sending messages up the view hierarchy with a PreferenceKey updated from the child view. But you have to dig around to find it, while this deprecated setValue() technique is still being widely recommended.

After years of getting away with easy screen rotation by hacking UIDevice, developers have been curbed by Apple. The thinking: those UIDevice values are read-only for a good reason as they could shift completely in subsequent versions. According to [one discussion](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/712247):

> “It was a bug that this setValue:forKey: technique ever had an effect.
> It should never have been used by any apps. This behavior has now been
> fixed so that the setValue:forKey: technique no longer has an effect."

So there you go. I'm putting this answer up in hopes it will spare other developers the frustration. Alan Quatermain's [approach found here on Github](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQUI/blob/master/Sources/AQUI/OrientationLock.swift) worked EDIT: for a while until we upgraded to iOS14. :( (See my comment below.)

Comment: Hi John, any progress since? The solution linked in your answer did not work.

Comment: No, and in fact since updating from iOS13 to iOS14 it doesn't seem to work for me anymore either beause we were no longer using SceneDelegate or AppDelegate. :( I gave up and made the whole app lock to landscape. I believe that for iOS16 there may be a better way.

Comment: How can such a simple feature entail such a headache! I ended up attributing screenWidth to the view height and vise versa, and applied a 90 degree rotation; couldn't be more uncomfortable about this solution, but it's a simple chart view, and there aren't any other options.

Comment: Yep, same here. I realized we had only 1-2 screens that needed to be rotated. So it’s imitation navigation bars and sideways text all around …