# how to set orientation in Portrait only?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to set UIViewController in Portrait, I tried to add

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation) preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation != UIDeviceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

But when I take my phone in Landscape, then enter this UIViewController,

I will run into Landscape first, then rotate to portrait!

but I don't want it shows landscape, I want it show portrait immediate,

Is there any wrong setting?

**EDIT**

I called the error ViewController "vcA",  it present from "vcB"

in vcB's `viewDidAppear`, I called

`[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];`

then vcA will show in landscape(if vcB was in landscape),

if add a few delay like:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
});
```

it will show portrait, but I do not know why it happen!

**ANSWER**

Finally, I found root cause!

1. when I launch app, it stay in Portrait mode,
2. After launch, vcB is first VC I called,
3. Phone stay in landscape, so when `viewDidAppear` in vcB, it call
   rotate to Landscape
4. At same time in viewDidAppear, I also call `present:vcA`
5. So currently, view have to do both rotate to landscape and present
   vcA(should in Portrait!!)
6. Then the bad situation happened!

**Solution**

Just disable rotate for first launch in "vcB", then in `viewDidAppear`, it will only call `present:vcA`

Thanks all a lot!

Comment: have you tried using viewWillAppear to force the view to be portrait?

Comment: Yes, I've tried. It can rotate to portrait correctly, But it also show in landscape first, how can I disable landscape view? I don want to show landscape, it's not supported!

Comment: @Devin check this answer maybe can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308919/unable-to-force-uiviewcontroller-orientation/38308987#38308987

Comment: Finally, I found the answer,~thanks a lot

Answer (score 13):

1. Go to General settings of your xcode project
2. Find deployment info
3. Check the device orientation to portrait only.

   [image]

OR

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

   [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]forKey:@"orientation"];
 }

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return NO;
 }
```

Comment: I only want to set portrait in current viewcontroller, change in General is no appropriate to me,  I try to add function in viewWillAppear, but it still show landscape first!

Comment: Yes,  I also tried this!  It will stop in landscape. I found something may make it happen, I'll add it soon!

Answer (score 7):

1. Select your project->Target->Project->General
2. Check and uncheck according to the screenshot(Under Deployment)
3. Make sure you check requires full screen or else you can not submit your app to app store.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In ***Xcode version 13.2.1***

and project with `SceneDelegate`,

the situation is not as web usual,

```
class AppDelegate{
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    }
}
```

it works

---

The following not works well

[image: 44]