# Portrait mode all views except one view to be rotated programatically to landscape under a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, orientation, screen-orientation

First of all, my project hierarchy:

```
tab bar controller -> navigation master -> view controllers
```

I have one page I want to rotate in landscape mode.

My project is compatible with all the device orientation modes.

[image]

I've manually frozen all the view controllers with autorotation returning false:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

except the one I want to rotate. S

I'm trying this in the view controller I want to be displayed in landscape:

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

But does nothing.

Also, I experimented an issue with this method. When the app was starting in landscape, the view was displaying in landscape and was unable to rotate. I manage to fix it with this method In my app delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if(self.restrictRotation == false){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait//UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait
    }
    else{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All//UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll
    }
}
```

And in viewDidLoad setting the var to true where I want to allow rotations:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.restrictRotation = true
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

I've tested with the debugger and the method `application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?)` is called, but the app don't rotate. I guess is because with a tab bar and a navigation controller, things has to be done differently, but don't know how exactly. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38308919/unable-to-force-uiviewcontroller-orientation/38308987#38308987 I hope this helps you